# Display text behind border

Tags: html, css

I have a carousel which works by having a larger `div` inside a smaller `div` which is offset positioned to emulate pages.

My outer fixed width `div` has a gray border around it and I'm noticing that the text from the inner `div` sits on top of that border.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/ruqrb567/

```
<div>
    <div>
    Testing Testing
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the text to sit behind the border?

---

EDIT: The inner div's width is required for the sliding mechanism of the carousel so this cannot be removed as a solution.

Comment: You could use `overflow: hidden` on your `<div>` to prevent the text to leave the box.

Comment: I don't know if you just want it to go behind (or) cut off the extra portions. If you want it to just go behind, you could try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ruqrb567/1/).

Comment: What is your use-case @Curt? Is it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ruqrb567/5/ ? Or like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ruqrb567/6/

Comment: i think z-index is applied but what effect you what to show can be manage with differentiating the little bit opacity to the inner div's text as i  suggest this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ruqrb567/3/)

hi try this by adding to your parent div and give class

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1**

You should remove the `widht` from the second `div`. You have a bigger `width` then the parent div that causes the text go over the border.

```
    div > div{

        border:0;
        z-index:1;
        color:blue;

    }
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ruqrb567/2/)**

**OPTION 2**

Or you can add a `<p>` element to the markup and add the same `width` as parent `div`

**CSS**

```
div
{
    width:44px;
    height:50px;
    border:solid 20px gray;
    z-index:2;
}

div > div{
width: 1000px;
    border:0;
    z-index:1;
    color:blue;

}

div > div > p{
   width: 44px;
    color:blue;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>Testing Testing</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ruqrb567/4/)**

**OPTION 3**

You can put the text under the parent div

**CSS**

```
div > div{
    position: relative;
    width:1000px;
    border:0;
    z-index:-1;
    color:blue;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ruqrb567/7/)**

Comment: I need the width for the carousel. My jsfiddle is just a demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove width of `div > div` class. Which has `width:1000px` it cause the problem.
check fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ruqrb567/

```
div
{
    width:44px;
    height:50px;
    border:solid 20px gray;
    z-index:2;
}

div > div{

    border:0;
    z-index:1;
    color:blue;

}

<div>
    <div>
    Testing Testing
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the width for the carousel. My jsfiddle is just a demonstration of the problem.